# Use differnt version of artifact downloaded by Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Maven download automatically dependency hierarchy for some dependency but I want to use different version in my project. What is the best way to import the right version that I need in my Java program.

[image]

I need to use parquet 1.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for the dependency you like to change in your pom.xml file. You can then specify the expected version `<version></version>`

Comment: but it not main dependency so its not written in pom.xml

Comment: if you want to fix the dependency to a specific version you either have to exclude the dependency from the main dependency which causes the problems (answer from algor) or add it explicitly (answer from manuel s.). Probably you can specify it in the `pluginManagement` block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exclusions?

```
<dependency>
....
<exclusion>
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
</exclusion>
....
</dependency>
```

Comment: 1. Add exclusion to the dependency:

<dependency>
....
<exclusion>
<artifactId>parquet-hadoop-bundle</artifactId>
<groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
</exclusion>
....
</dependency>

2. Add explicit dependency
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
 <artifactId>parquet-hadoop-bundle</artifactId>
 <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
But it's not guaranteed that third party library will work with the given dependency.